# Assign torch.cuda.FloatTensor

Tags: numpy, gpu, pytorch

I'd like to know how can I do the following code, **but now using pytorch, 
where dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor**. There's the code straight python (using numpy):

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
xmax, xmin = 5, -5
pop = 30
x = (xmax-xmin)*rand.random(pop,1)
y = x**2
[minz, indexmin] = np.amin(y), np.argmin(y)  
best = x[indexmin]
```

**This is my attempt to do it:**

```
import torch
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
def fit (position):
    return  position**2
def main():
    pop = 30
    xmax, xmin = 5, -5
    x= (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop, 1).type(dtype)+xmin
    y = fit(x)
    [miny, indexmin] = torch.min(y,0)
    best = x[indexmin]
    print(best)
```

The last part where I define the variable best as the value of x with index equal to indexmin it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here.

**The following messenge appears:**

```
RuntimeError: expecting vector of indices at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1501971235237/work/pytorch-0.1.12/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorIndex.cu:405
```

Comment: Hey! I cannot reproduce the error. I'm on a different pytorch version, and it runs just fine. Could you please run `conda list | grep pytorch` from the terminal?

Comment: @cleros thank you!
**Sorry but I've posted the wrong code**
    import torch
    dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
    def fit (x):
        return  x**2
    def main():
        pop = 30
        xmax, xmin = 5, -5
        x = (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop, 1).type(dtype)+xmin
        y = fit(x)
        [miny, indexmin] = torch.min(y,0)
        best = x[indexmin]  
        print(best)
        main()

This is the code that gives me the error. 

**2)**
When I run grep pytorch: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works fine in pytorch `0.2`. Let me analyze your code so that you can identify the problem.

```
x= (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop, 1).type(dtype)+xmin
y = fit(x)
```

Here, `x` and `y` is a 2d tensor of shape `30x1`. In the next line:

```
[miny, indexmin] = torch.min(y,0)
```

The returned tensor `miny` is a 2d tensor of shape `30x1` and `indexmin` is a 1d tensor of size `1`. So, when you execute:

```
best = x[indexmin]
```

It (probably) gives error (in old pytorch version) because `x` is a 2d tensor of shape `30x1` and `indexmin` is a 1d tensor of size `1`. To resolve this error, you can simply do:

```
best = x.squeeze()[indexmin] # x.squeeze() returns a 1d tensor of size `30`
```

**Please note**, a 2d tensor of shape `30x1` is same as a 1d tensor of size `30`. So, you can modify your program as follows.

```
import torch
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
def main():
    pop, xmax, xmin = 30, 5, -5
    x= (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)+xmin
    y = torch.pow(x, 2)
    minz, indexmin = y.min(0)
    best = x[indexmin]
    print(best)

main()
```